# Help with Matrix Regression

Tags: matrices, regression

The question i have is:

Consider two independent random variables $ξ_1$ and $ξ_2$, such that $ξ_1 ∼ N(0,1) $ and $ ξ_2 ∼ N(0,2)$. Let $η_1 =(ξ_1+ξ_2, ξ_2)^{T} ,η_2 =(ξ_1, ξ_1−ξ_2)^{T}$. Find the covariance matrix between $η_1$ and $η_2$.

How do i calculate the Covariance Matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\eta_j(i)$ denote the $i$th element of vector $\eta_j$ with $j =1,2$.

By definition, we have

$\text{cov}(\eta_1,\eta_2) =  \left( \begin{array}{cc} cov(\eta_1(1),\eta_2(1)) & cov(\eta_1(1),\eta_2(2)) \\ cov(\eta_1(2),\eta_2(1)) & cov(\eta_1(2),\eta_2(2)) \end{array} \right),$

where direct substitution gives

$\text{cov}(\eta_1,\eta_2) =  \left( \begin{array}{cc} cov(\xi_1+\xi_2,\xi_1) & cov(\xi_1+\xi_2,\xi_1-\xi_2) \\ cov(\xi_2,\xi_1) & cov(\xi_2,\xi_1-\xi_2) \end{array} \right).$

From here you apply the definition of the covariance operator for two scalar-valued random variables and that of independence. You should get

$\text{cov}(\eta_1,\eta_2) =  \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 2 \end{array} \right).$